# Making sure that faces have the same dimensions

Tags: transforms, faces, scale

this is my very first try at using Blender so sorry in advance for the noobish question.

I have this very simple object (supposed to be a window): 
[image]

I'd like to find a way to be sure that face A as the same width as face B (and potentially top and bottom faces too).

I created this object using extrusion on a simple cube... I don't even know if I was supposed to this that way.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: Open the User Preferences and select Addons, find and enable MeasureIt. Now in the main view click the new Display panel and Show and click Segment.

Comment: you could also delete your face A, duplicate face B and snap it on the left so that it replaces face A

Comment: @moonboots hey thanks for your answer... I'm talking about faces but obviously it's a 3D object. Will your technique work with a group of faces?

Comment: yes of course, enable the Snap option (Vertex mode) on the bottom horizontal menu bar (you can either press ctrl which is a shortcut for snap), also enable the Automatically Merge option (on the right of the snap). Then, when you'll move the B copy on the X axis, you'll make it snap at the right position. You just need to point with your cursor what vertex of the B face copy is supposed to snap.

Answer (score 0):

I went with @moonboots answer (all glory to him).

- Delete the group of faces that A is composed of
- Duplicate the group of faces that B is composed of
- Snap that duplicate at A's position